# if(boolean) does not execute?

Tags: java, ms-access, boolean

I am using an MS Access database where I store Man of the Match as a Yes/No check-box. The purpose of the code below is to check if the check-box is ticked. If it is ticked then add one to TotalMoM.

The problem is TotalMoM is always 1 (even if more than one check-box is ticked) or 0 (if zero check-boxes are ticked).

```
try
    {
        String filename = "Database.mdb";
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
        database += filename.trim() + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=false";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");

        for(int x = 1; x < 18; x++)//will repeat 18 times (once for each team fixture)
        {
            Statement sta = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblPlayers WHERE PlayerID = "+ PlayerID +" AND FixtureNumber = "+ x);

            while (rs.next())
            {
            MoM = false; //initialising variable
            TotalMoM = 0;
            MoM = rs.getBoolean("MoM");
            if (MoM){ //if Man of the Match checkbox is ticked
                TotalMoM = TotalMoM + 1; //calculating total
            }
            jLabel12.setText(String.valueOf(TotalMoM));   
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println("Exception e:" + e);
    }
```

Comment: Checkbox being ticked doesn't necessarily imply that the value fetched from the db is `true`.  Print it to figure what it is.

Comment: You're resetting `TotalMoM=0;` at each passage through the loop. Do it once before the loop.

Comment: Thanks Anton, guess I've been staring at the screen too hard for too long :)

Comment: @AntonH this should be an answer.

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, I know. But since it's a small mistake, I feel it's such a small answer, it's not necessary. Main thing is correcting mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 MoM = false; //initialising variable
 TotalMoM = 0;
 while (rs.next())
        {

        MoM = rs.getBoolean("MoM");
        if (MoM){ //if Man of the Match checkbox is ticked
            TotalMoM = TotalMoM + 1; //calculating total
        }
        jLabel12.setText(String.valueOf(TotalMoM));
```